# $C^*$-homomorphisms and compact $T_2$ spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

Let $A,B$ be both $T_2$ and compact s.t. $A \underbrace{\cong}_{\text{ homeo.}} B$. Show that $C(A)$ and $C(B)$ are $star$-isomorphic.

Proof:
set up $h: A \rightarrow B$ as a homeomorphism and claim that $C(h): C(B) \rightarrow C(A) : \ f \mapsto f \circ h$ is a unital $star$-homomorphism.

1. Linearity:
   $ ((f + \lambda g) \circ h)(x) = f((h(x)) + \lambda g (h(x))) = (f \circ h + \lambda g \circ h)(x),$
2. Multiplicativity:  $(f \circ g) ( g \circ h) (x) = f(g \circ h)(x)
                                    = ((fg) \circ h) (x),$
3. Involution Preserving:  $(\overline{f} \circ h)(x) = \overline{f}(x)
       = (\overline{f \circ h})(x)$.

So I am a bit confused about the unital part i.e. $1 \circ h = 1$ and the bijective part.

Answer (score 2):

The unital part: note that the units of the $C^*$-algebras are the functions that are constantly equal to $1$.

The surjective part: if $f\in C(A)$, then $f\circ h^{-1}\in C(B)$ and $C(h)(f\circ h^{-1})=f$.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I have noticed that you are using $f \mapsto f \circ h^{-1}$ instead of $   f \circ h    $? Is that just for the bijectice part? And what about the three steps I have done are they ok?

Comment: @Fredf What do you mean instead of? I'm just saying: take $f\in C(A)$, compose it with the inverse $h^{-1}$ to get a map in $C(B)$. Then this map is mapped to $f$ by $C(h)$. Your 3 steps: the second one has a small mistake maybe $g$ should be $h$, but anyway it is trivial $C(h)(fg)=(fg)\circ h$ and $(fg)\circ h(x)=(fg)(h(x))=f(h(x))g(h(x))=(f\circ h)(x)\cdot (g\circ h)(x)$